# Software for Domain Names Availability

Tags: windows-7, windows

Are there automated software that helps you check for domain combination and availability?

Running Windows 7

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Whilst I do not know any native programs that run on Windows 7 for this, you are much better off using a web site that is totally independent to the operating system such as the ["Domain Suggestions"](http://domain-suggestions.domaintools.com/) section of [Domain Tools](http://www.domaintools.com).

For example, if I type in test:

[image]

Comment: +1 Good answer, mostly because I think the SO is looking for names available and the suggestions shows available combinations.  Nice.  I was going to suggest that `WHOIS`  http://whois.org/ has been providing this service over http since at least 1993.

Answer (score 1):

http://domai.nr/

http://www.domaintools.com/

http://www.domainsbot.com/

and to keep your name consistent amongst social networks

http://namechk.com/